# Samba permissions between 2 linux machines

Tags: server, permissions, samba

Been pulling my hair out for days over this. I'm sure the problem lies not with the samba configuration itself, but permissions, and I'm at a loss to figure out what's wrong!

Here's my samba share configuration:

```
[documents]
comment = documents
path = /allspark/documents
vaild users = carlo, natalie, @smbusers
browsable = yes
guest ok = no
read only = no
force group = smbusers
create mask = 0775
force directory mode = 2775
```

I've got the 2 users: `carlo` and `natalie` in the `smbusers` group. `/allspark/documents` is owned by `chief` and the group `smbusers` (`chief` is the main login on the server).

In windows, I access my share with `carlo` and all is good, I have all the correct permissions and the files are owned by me. On the laptop with Ubuntu, and logging in as `natalie`, when I connect to the share and try to copy a file into the share I get an error message saying the file cannot be found.

I think the problem may lie with the Ubuntu laptop and permissions. On the laptop as user `natalie` I can make a new folder and checking the permissions via `ls -l` shows it's correct. The problem seems to lie with dragging files from the laptop to `/documents`. I can save a new file to the server but after that cannot access it. Checking permissions it says that I don't own the file but I made it just two seconds ago!

Comment: Is it possibly because its in your root folder?

Comment: 1) Why in the world are you using samba to share directories between two Linux machines? Is there any reason for that? If not, use NFS, it is far more straightforward. 2. Please [edit] your question and specify what OS you have on the server and what on the client. 3) Show the output of `ls -ld` on both `/allspark/` _and_ `/allspark/documents` 4) Tell us exactly what permissions you want 5) Explain if you are mapping the samba users to Linux ones.

Comment: I'm using samba because the directory is also shared between a windows computer. I have ubuntu server 12.04 LTS on the server and 12.04 LTS desktop on the client. I managed to solve this in the end by forcing uid=natalie on the client, after this everything works as expected. Thanks for taking the time to read my question.